# SQL server - Insert string record containing backslash

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a record in the table where one of the column has following value.

`\\\\a\\b\\c`

```
Database DataProvider = new SqlDatabase(connectionstring);  
DataProvider.ExecuteNonQuery("sprocname",
                    Id,
                    qText,
                );
```

Here, `qText` has above value. After execution, the value gets added in the table as `\` (single backslash) only.

If I try to insert the record manually in the table,

```
INSERT INTO mytbl(id, q) VALUES
 (0, '\\\\a\\b\\c')
```

proper value gets inserted. Any reason why this is happening? Am I missing anything here?

**UPDATE**

It seems that whatever my string is, only it's first letter getting inserted in that column! Not sure why. The datatype of the column is `varchar(max)`

Ex.

```
for qText = 'abc', then column has value `a`
for qText = '\\\\a\\b\\c', then column has value `\`
```

Answer (score 5):

Backslash is an escape sequence character, so two backslashes will be interpreted as one backslash. If you want to keep your backslashes as it is in this case use verbatim string literal which adds @ at the beginning of the string literal.

```
var qText = @"\\\\a\\b\\c";
```

Answer (score 0):

While storing the `\` in a string variable, you need to add it as an escape sequence `"\\"`

So, if we write

```
String qText = "\\"
```

the value of `qText` will be `\`

Therefore to store `\\\\a\\b\\c`, you should assign double the number of `\`.

```
String qText = "\\\\\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c"
```

This way when used, the value of qText will be `\\\\a\\b\\c`

Comment: Have you tried changing the data type of the column?

Comment: Also, please share the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the stored procedure. The input parameter for the procedure was `varchar`, but length was not specified.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @FelixPamittan, you were a second faster ;-)